# Is there a way to undo deletion of a tab group in Safari?

Tags: safari, tabs

I'm diving into tab groups which seems pretty much ideal for the kind of browsing I do.

I just noticed that the right-click delete action on a tab group does **not** ask for confirmation, deletes the entire group and there is no way to undo it. That can't be for real, can it?